# Почему echo выводит только "<"?

Tags: php, html

Сервер получает json-файл с четырьмя значениями:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("file.json");
$content = json_decode($content, true);

$title = $content['title'];
$short_title = $content['short_title'];
$content = $content['content'];
$table_of_contents = $content['table_of_contents'];
?>
```

Первые три переменные выводятся нормально, а четвёртое – новое, добавленное – выводит только "<" при любом значении в json-файле:

```
<script>
    let table_of_contents = `<?= $table_of_contents; ?>`
    if (table_of_contents) { console.log(table_of_contents) } // Выводит "<"

    let title = `<?= $title; ?>`
    if (title) { console.log(title) } // Выводит что нужно
</script>
```

Содержимое json:

```
{"title":"Тайтл","short_title":"Короткий тайтл","content":"Контент","table_of_contents":"Содержание"}
```

Какая может быть проблема?

Comment: Как минимум, в самом начале нужно заменить `<php` на `<?php`

Comment: А вообще, было бы неплохо приложить содержимое json файла

Comment: Ну это я так здесь написал... В коде правильно...

Comment: *"Ну это я так здесь написал... В коде правильно.."*  --- тут надо писать **точно так же**, как у вас в коде. Иначе вы не дождётесь правильного ответа, т.к. каждый ответ на 100% зависит от того, что написано в коде

Comment: Блин, я понял. Я определяю $table_of_contents из переменной $content, которую переопределил строкой выше - $content = $content['content'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот почему

```
$content = file_get_contents("file.json");
$content = json_decode($content, true);

$title = $content['title'];
$short_title = $content['short_title'];
$content = $content['content']; // На этой строке массив $content заменяется на "Контент"
$table_of_contents = $content['table_of_contents'];
```

Переименуйте хотя бы так

```
$contentValue = $content['content'];
```